# Closing multiple iTerm2 tabs makes zsh_history lose most of the history

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I use zsh 5.8 (oh-my-zsh + my custom configs) with iTerm2.

I want every zsh instance to store the command to the history every time I type it and *share* the history with the others.

It basically works as I want, but the problem is, if I (manually) quit iTerm2 with multiple tabs open (e.g. so that I can recover those tabs after reboot), the `zsh_history` file loses most of its content and contains only the first N commands.

My guess is the zsh instances kind of compete with each other in the last moment.

`HISTSIZE` and `SAVEHIST` are set largely enough (10000000).

`setopt` prints:

```
alwaystoend
autocd
autopushd
noclobber
completeinword
extendedhistory
noflowcontrol
histexpiredupsfirst
histfcntllock
histignoredups
histignorespace
histverify
incappendhistory
interactive
interactivecomments
login
longlistjobs
monitor
promptsubst
pushdignoredups
pushdminus
sharehistory
shinstdin
zle
```

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

**EDIT**: After seeing the comment, I disabled `inc_append_history`, but it's happening again.

**EDIT2**: Disabled `appendhistory` as well, but still the same.

**EDIT3**: After manually unsetting `histsavebycopy` (i.e., `nohistsavebycopy`), looking good so far.

**EDIT4**: Since the last change (EDIT3), I've experienced `zsh: corrupt history file` once.

**EDIT5**: Lost some history even without the `corrupt history file` error.

Comment: `incappendhistory` and `sharehistory` should prevent what you describe...

Comment: @noname : How did you set `HISTFILE`?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I thought so, and actually I set those options a long time ago 

Comment: @user1934428 It is `~/.zsh_history` (iirc it is the default of oh-my-zsh).

Comment: @noname : Do you have set both incappendhistory  and sharehistory ? According to the zsh man page, these options are mutually exclusive, and IMHO, you should set **only** sharehistory.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for pointing out! I hope correcting this fixes the issue I'm having as well.

Comment: @user1934428 That was indeed a helpful comment, but it did not fix my issue. Thanks anyway.